# Identifying the decoder that OpenCV VideoCapture's read() uses

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am sure I am not the first person with such a question but searching for opencv and license only led me to questions about recognizing license plates. That's why I am forced to ask this question here. My apologies if it is the wrong forum.

We are trying to build a commercial web application. A part of it involves reading videos from a webcam, processing it, and writing it to a file. We want to be careful to avoid accidentally GNU’ing our code, but also avoid the onerous licensing that would come from usage of codes like MP4 which we simply can't afford. We think we've avoided the GPL'ing by removing ffmpeg from our machine. But the camera we read from (using RTSP if it matters) uses the h.264 encoding. We use OpenCV’s Video reader to read it, though we save it out in the web format.

What we are unsure of is whether the Video reader uses a version that keeps us legal. Is there any command or Python cv2 function that can tell us what we use?

To put it differently, we are using the OpenCV library and would like to know if we have issues related to GNU or to have to pay royalties. Thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg is a library. you can link it dynamically (as OpenCV does) and then its license doesn't affect you (or OpenCV). AFAIK OpenCV isn't under GPL, it has some other license (see source). disclaimer: IANAL.

Comment: Thank you. I did some more research. Since OpenCV assures you on the website that it can be used commercially ("OpenCV is open source and released under the BSD 3-Clause License. It is free for commercial use.") we will go ahead. IANAL either of course.